# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory does not include directory entries

Tags: c#, zip, uwp, unzip

I have a basic Windows 10 UWP app and use the following code to create a .zip file from a directory structure:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("/inputpath", "/output.zip");
```

I noticed that the resulting .zip file does not have any entries for nested directories, thus unzipping on a Mac does not work.

Here is the directory structure that I want to include in the zip file:

```
./ziproot
    ./Data
        Version.txt
```

What I get using the API `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(...)`:

```
$ zipinfo output.zip 
Archive:  output.zip   279202 bytes   4 files
-rw----     2.0 fat        1 b- defN 13-May-16 11:33 Data\Version.txt
```

When I use the Windows explorer to compress the test folder, I get the correct zip structure:

```
$ zipinfo zipwindows.zip 
Archive:  zipwindows.zip   279188 bytes   8 files
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 b- stor 18-May-16 09:05 Data/
-rw----     2.0 fat        1 t- stor 13-May-16 11:33 Data/Version.txt
```

Note the first entry for the `Data` directory in the output above.

Is there a way to have the `ZipFile` API include entries for directories without having to traverse the directory myself?

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, the problem was something else:

`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()` uses a backslash in path names. Archives made with the Windows file explorer use a forward slash (that's what I needed, too).

I don't see a way to change this default behavior of `ZipFile` and instead used `ZipArchive` to build the zip file myself. By doing this, I didn't even need to include entries for directories.

Those are added by appending a forward slash to the end of the path, by the way (e.g. `foo/bar/`).

Answer (score 1):

Good day, does this work for you?

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("/inputpath", "/Output.zip", CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. No, this does not work for me, because it does not add entries for directories. The first example output is from using CreateFromDirectory(). It's missing the entry for the "Data" folder.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, you specified `true` at the end?

Comment: It turned out the problem was caused by something else: ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory uses a backslash to separate folders, but I needed a forward slash.  The zip file created by the Windows explorer used  a forward slash.