# PowerShell to zip WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, powershell, zip

I have a folder containing the code for a WordPress plugin, and the following script:

```
$folder = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $pluginName
$destination = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "bundles/$pluginName.zip"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

if (Test-Path $destination) {
    Remove-Item $destination
}

[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory(
    $folder,
    $destination,
    [IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal,
    $true # include base directory
)
```

If I try to install the plugin by uploading the produced zip file to a local WordPress instance, I get the following errors:

> Warning: copy(/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api\jwt-auth.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 257
>
> Warning: copy(/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api\jwt-auth.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 257
>
> Could not copy file. /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api\jwt-auth.php
>
> Plugin install failed.

However, if I manually zip the plugin, by right-clicking the plugin folder in Windows Explorer and choosing "Send to..." -> "Compressed folder", the generated zip file installs fine.

I can't figure out why this happens, because if I unzip the folders and `diff` their contents, they are identical. (The zipped files are not, but I assume that's because of compression levels etc).

Do I have to set any specific flags when zipping to make this work? How do I script production of a zip file that works *exactly* like "Send to..." -> "Compressed folder"?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet instead?

Comment: @James Yes, with exactly the same results.

Comment: @JamesRuskin I also tried writing an equivalent bash script and run it under WSL; it works! But why?

Comment: The problem may be that `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()` / `Compress-Archive` uses backslashes in path names (rather than forward slashes). It looks like your plugin is being installed on a POSIX OS (Linux/Unix/MacOS etc). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292799 suggests using `ZipArchive` instead.